# I want to access inputed Value in JSON array using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

i created array 'PROPERTIES' which accept value like username, password,sid etc.And i want to access this entered value using javascript.

```
     'PROPERTIES': {'gatewayurl': 
     {'Name': 
        {
         'en': 'Input gatewayurl'
     },

        'Description': {
         'en': 'Input gatewayurl for sms gateway'
     },
     'Type': 'string',
     'Required': 'Y',
     'Multiple': 'N',
     'Default': '',
  },
  'username': 
     {'Name': 
        {
         'en': 'Input username'
     },

        'Description': {
         'en': 'Input username'
     },
     'Type': 'string',
     'Required': 'Y',
     'Multiple': 'N',
     'Default': '{=Document:NAME}',
  },
   'password': 
     {'Name': 
        {
         'en': 'Input string'
     },

        'Description': {
         'en': 'Input password'
     },
     'Type': 'string',
     'Required': 'Y',
     'Multiple': 'N',
     'Default': '{=Document:NAME}',
  },
   'sid': 
     {'Name': 
        {
         'en': 'Input string'
     },

        'Description': {
         'en': 'Input sid'
     },
     'Type': 'string',
     'Required': 'Y',
     'Multiple': 'N',
     'Default': '{=Document:NAME}',
  },
   'mobileno': 
     {'Name': 
        {
         'en': 'Input mobileno'
     },

        'Description': {
         'en': 'Input mobileno'
     },
     'Type': 'number',
     'Required': 'Y',
     'Multiple': 'N',
     'Default': null,
  },
  'message': 
     {'Name': 
        {
         'en': 'Input message'
     },

        'Description': {
         'en': 'Input message'
     },
     'Type': 'string',
     'Required': 'Y',
     'Multiple': 'N',
     'Default': null,
      }

},
```

> i Used php code But i want Access value using only Javascript Please Some one Help me

```
$url =$_REQUEST["properties"]["gatewayurl"];
$user = $_REQUEST["properties"]["username"];
$password = $_REQUEST["properties"]["password"];
$sid = $_REQUEST["properties"]["sid"];
$number= $_REQUEST["properties"]["mobileno"];
$message= $_REQUEST["properties"]["message"];
```

Comment: what it does to do with php?

Comment: what exactly you want?

Comment: #Ninju i want get this inputed value like username, password,mobileno etc using javascript, Not using php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "PROPERTIES" is an array as you were saying you should initialize it as an array.

```
var PROPERTIES = [ {'gatewayurl' ........... }]
```

Then you can get values by

```
var url = PROPERTIES[0].gatewayurl;
var user = PROPERTIES[0].username;
var password = PROPERTIES[0].password;
var sid = PROPERTIES[0].sid;
```

etc..

If its a JSON Array as shown in your example,

```
var REQUEST = { 
    'PROPERTIES': {'gatewayurl' ... }
 }
```

Then you can get values by

```
var url = REQUEST["properties"]["gatewayurl"];
var user = REQUEST["properties"]["username"];
var password = REQUEST["properties"]["password"];
var sid = REQUEST["properties"]["sid"];
```

Comment: thanks for Answer, but your answer in php. I want to get value in only Javascript.please help me

Comment: Normally we use var Recipient = document.getElementById("recipient").value; for html form.But now i Want this for JSON

Comment: So you want to create a JSON array from HTML Form.  Use a form and get each values by 
 document.getElementById("myForm").elements[0].value
 make it a object and push that object in to your JSON array

Comment: No u getting wrong,i did not created html form,i am just giving example. I created only JSON array is shown in above code and now i want to store the inputed value in array like username in var using javascript